# Importing modules in python script and figuring out layout of directory/package

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I am very new to python...and I have been reading around trying to figure out a better answer... but I am still struggling.

I was trying to import some script to get code talking to each other. I've tried importing as suggested via python documentation:

```
from SomePackage.somefile import object
```

The actual directory looks like this

```
Foo/
├── bin
│   
├── README.txt
├── setup.py
├── development.ini
├── SomePackage
│   ├── somefile
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── object.py
│   ├── __init__.py
```

Do I need to import in my .py file with? Each module has an empty **init**.py file. Should I move where my program is located?

Any help is truly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you using any framework? how do you start application flow in this structure?

Comment: I have a setup.py doc that tells  python:

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue! I need to create a setup.py document that created the packages and modules!

```
setup(

    #contents
    packages=['somepackage', 'somepackage.someotherpackage'],
    py_modules=['somepackage.module.file.py'],
    scripts=['bin/somescript-cmd'], 
    #more code...
```